# EWS create appointment without getting a streaming notification

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm working on synchronization from our application to Exchange and back. I've set up a streamingnotification to the calendar of a room/resource defined in Exchange.

When I create an appointment in the calendar of the room I get a notification in my application, which is great. However, I also want to change this appointment from our application and send these changes to the calendar of the room in Exchange. That is no problem, but then I also receive a notification from Exchange. Basically Exchange is telling me that item 'x' has changed, when I'm the one who changed it, so I already know and don't want to process this change.

Is there a way to determine where the change originated from, or tell EWS to not send a streamingnotification when I edit an item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you change an Item in EWS with UpdateItem the lasted ChangeKey is returned in the Response https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605828(v=exchg.150).aspx . This property allows you to track when changes occur on the Item or to validate if no changes has occurred since the last modification.

The PidTagLastModifierEntryId property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg672131(v=exchg.80).aspx will tell you who last modified an appointment.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it will require a bit more administration, but it should do the trick.